# Access denied for .Net GetProcesses

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm having trouble connecting to remote computer to grab a list of processes running.
For my test machine I'm using the username @"ownme\veritas".  The password is just "veritas".
The sample domain is "ownme".

```
return new System.Management.ConnectionOptions()
{
    //certainly these variables have been checked and are correct
    Username = UserCredential.DomainUser,
    Password = UserCredential.Password
};
```

This is where I'm trying to do the connection.  I don't know, but this might actually be the issue here.  It could also be I didn't fill out enough fields in the ConnectionOptions above.
I referred to these two articles:

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23514935/How-to-use-GetProcess-for-remote-sytems.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.authentication.aspx

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope($"\\\\{computer.DnsHostname}\\root\\cimv2", connectionOptions);
scope.Connect();

//Error: Access is denied
var processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses(dnsHostName);
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetProcesses` will use the current users credentials to connect to the remote machine, not the credentials you specified via `ConnectionOptions`.

You need to use the WMI scope object that you created with the correct credentials to issue a query for the processes like this:

```
//..

SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Process"); //query processes

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    using (ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get())
    {
        foreach (var process in collection) //loop through results
        {
            var name = process["name"]; //process name
            //Do something with process
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize this was such a highly viewed question:  I found the answer a long time ago.  I actually didn't use WMI to do it.  We actually filed a ticket with Microsoft and they discounted us for free after they gave us the answer.  The answer is:

`LogonUser` + `NEW_CREDENTIALS`